# Excel to Azure SQL with query parameters

Tags: excel, azure, azure-sql-database

How would a load data into Excel from Azure SQL with a parametrized SQL Query?

e.g.: `SELECT FieldOne,FieldTwo FROM SomeTable WHERE FieldThree=[Sheet1$A1]`

`[Sheet1$A1]` should be replaced with the value from the corresponding cell.

I must use "SQL Server" connection. I found solution in SO for "Microsoft Query" but I cannot connect to Azure SQL via "Microsoft Query".